# Lifting subobject classifier of a category to its arrow category

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I'm reading Goldblatt's Topoi and trying to practice categorical reasoning, generalizing the example of $\mathbf{Set}^\rightarrow$ being a topos.

So, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with a subobject classifier $\Omega, \top$ where $\top : \mathbf{1} \rightarrow \Omega$. Consider the arrow category $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$: does it have a subobject classifier?

I think that it does: $\text{id}_\Omega, (\top, \top)$ seems like a good candidate. In particular, if $f, g$ are some monic arrows in $\mathcal{C}$ with characters $\chi_f, \chi_g$, then $(\chi_f, \chi_g)$ is the character of $(f, g)$ in $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$.

The construction I'm having in mind seems to follow from the structure of the proof I've done earlier that if $\mathcal{C}$ has pullbacks, then so does $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$ (namely, "gluing" two pullbacks of $\mathcal{C}$ in a cube-like diagram naturally compatible with the arrow category structure produces a pullback in $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$), but said proof is quite lengthy, so I'm omitting it here. The uniqueness of characters follows from the uniqueness of characters in $\mathcal{C}$.

So, my questions:

1. If $\mathcal{C}$ has S.C.s, then does $\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow$ also have them?
2. If it does, is the above indeed a S.C.?
3. If it is, why Goldblatt is using a seemingly more involved construct for the specific example of $\mathbf{Set}^\rightarrow$?

Comment: The problem with $\operatorname{id}_\Omega, (\top, \top)$ is: in order to get a commutative square $(\chi_f, \chi_g) : (\phi : X \to Y) \to \operatorname{id}_\Omega$, you require that $\chi_g \circ \phi = \chi_f$;  Therefore, you get *only* the subobjects of $X \to Y$ induced by a pullback square with a subobject $Y' \hookrightarrow Y$, which does not cover *all* the possible subobjects of $X \to Y$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler now that I've set this problem aside for a couple of weeks and got to it again I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question to ask would be: what *are* the monomorphisms of $\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}$?  To answer this question, let us use a Yoneda lemma style of argument: first, note that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}}(0 \to U, X \to Y) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(U, Y)$, and this isomorphism is natural in $Y$.  Thus, if $f : (X' \to Y') \to (X \to Y)$ is a monomorphism, then for every object $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$, we must have $f_2 \circ - : \operatorname{Hom}(U, Y') \to \operatorname{Hom}(U, Y)$ is injective; or in other words, $f_2 : Y' \to Y$ must be a monomorphism.  Similarly, $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow}(\operatorname{id}_U : U \to U, X \to Y) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(U, X)$, and so we get that if $f : (X' \to Y') \to (X \to Y)$ is a monomorphism, then $f_1 : X' \to X$ must be a monomorphism.

I will now leave it as an exercise to show that $f_1 : X' \to X$ and $f_2 : Y' \to Y$ being monomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ is also sufficient to get $f : (X' \to Y') \to (X \to Y)$ is a monomorphism in $\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}$.

---

So, now suppose we have a subobject classifier $\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}$.  Then let us focus first on $\Omega_2$: we will need that for any object $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$, we get
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(U, \Omega_2) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow}(0\to U, \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow}(0 \to U).$$
Now by the above, if $(X' \to Y') \to (0 \to U)$ is a monomorphism, then $X' \to 0$ is a monomorphism, so $X'$ is an initial object also; and also, $Y' \to U$ is a monomorphism.  So, $\operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}^\rightarrow}(0 \to U) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}}(U)$; and all steps are natural in $U$.  Now, we ask: is there an object of $\mathcal{C}$ which represents the last functor $\operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}}$?  Yes: $\Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$ does by definition.

Similarly, we will need
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(U, \Omega_1) \simeq \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(\operatorname{id}_U, \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2) \simeq \operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}}(\operatorname{id}_U).$$
Now, to get a monomorphism $(X \to Y) \to \operatorname{id}_U$, we will need to have $X \to U$ and $Y \to U$ being monomorphisms.  In addition, we will need for $X\to U$ to factor through $Y \to U$ in order for there to be a map $X \to Y$ making a commutative diagram.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}}(\operatorname{id}_U) & \simeq \{ (X, Y) \in \operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}}(U) \times \operatorname{Sub}_{\mathcal{C}}(U) \mid X \subseteq Y \} \\
& \simeq \{ (f, g) \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, \Omega) \times \operatorname{Hom}(U, \Omega) \mid f \le g \} \\
& \simeq \{ (f, g) \in \operatorname{Hom}(U, \Omega) \times \operatorname{Hom}(U, \Omega) \mid (f \rightarrow g) = \top \}.
\end{align*}
Again, all steps are natural in $U$; and we need to ask whether the last functor $\{ (f, g) : \operatorname{Hom}(-, \Omega) \times \operatorname{Hom}(-, \Omega) \mid (f \rightarrow g) = \top \}$ is representable.  I will now leave it as an exercise to show that the pullback in $\mathcal{C}$ of the morphisms $\rightarrow : \Omega_{\mathcal{C}} \times \Omega_{\mathcal{C}} \to \Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $\top : 1 \to \Omega_{\mathcal{C}}$ does represent this functor.

Finally, the morphism $\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ will be induced by the morphism of functors $(0_U, \operatorname{id}_U) : (0 \to U) \to \operatorname{id}_U$; if you trace through the isomorphisms of functors, you will see that the corresponding morphism $\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ is the composition of the pullback map $\Omega_1 \hookrightarrow \Omega \times \Omega$ with $\pi_2 : \Omega \times \Omega \to \Omega$.

---

It now remains to see whether the "necessary values" of $\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ constructed above actually form a subobject classifier.  I will just comment that in order to get a subobject of $f : X \to Y$, you need a subobject $X' \hookrightarrow X$ and a subobject $Y' \hookrightarrow Y$.  Now, once you have those two things, you also need a map $X' \to Y'$ which makes the diagram commute; note that since $Y' \hookrightarrow Y$ is a monomorphism, there can be at most one such map.  Also note that such a map exists if and only if $X' \hookrightarrow X$ factors through the pullback $Y' \times_Y X \hookrightarrow X$.  I will leave it as an exercise to show that this is equivalent to the condition that $\chi_{X'} \le \chi_{Y'} \circ f$ as members of the Heyting algebra $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}} (X, \Omega)$; and then to use this to conclude that a subobject of $X \to Y$ is equivalent to a morphism $(X \to Y) \to (\Omega_1 \to \Omega_2)$ in $\mathcal{C}^{\rightarrow}$.

Answer (score 3):

$\require{AMScd}$If $\cal E$ is an elementary topos, then so is the functor category ${\cal E}^C$ for every small category $C$; the classifying monomorphism is just the image of ${\sf true}:1 \hookrightarrow \Omega$ along the diagonal functor $\Delta : {\cal E} \to {\cal E}^C$.

To see this, you can consider the obvious map ${\cal E}^C(G, \Delta\Omega) \to \text{Sub}(G)$ that sends a morphism $g : G \to \Delta\Omega$ to the pullback of the square
$$
\begin{CD}
S(g) @>>> \Delta1 \\
@Vm_gVV @VVV \\
G @>>g> \Delta\Omega
\end{CD}
$$
Limits and monics in functor categories are defined objectwise, so this just means taking the pullback objectwise; explicitly, for each  $x\in\cal E$
$$
\begin{CD}
S(g)x @>>> 1 \\
@Vm_{g,x}VV @VVV \\
Gx @>>g> \Omega
\end{CD}
$$ is a pullback in $\cal E$. Such pullback $S(g) \hookrightarrow G$ exists, because $\cal E$ is a topos, and it is a monic.

It remains to show that every monic arises in this way. Given such a monic $\alpha : F \Rightarrow G$, each $\alpha_x : Fx \to Gx$ in $\cal E$ corresponds to a certain $\chi_x^\alpha : Gx \to \Omega$ by virtue of the bijection $\text{Sub}(Gx)\cong {\cal E}(Gx,\Omega)$; since now the collection $\chi_x^\alpha : Gx \to \Omega$ forms a cocone for $G$, it corresponds to a unique  natural transformation $\bar\chi^\alpha : G \Rightarrow \Delta\Omega$.

It is now just a matter of uwinding the definition to see that the pullback $m_{\bar\chi^\alpha} : S(\bar \chi^\alpha) \Rightarrow G$ coincides with $\alpha$, and conversely that if $g : G \Rightarrow \Delta\Omega$ is a morphism, $\bar\chi^{m_g} = g$.

Comment: Oh, that's a great answer, but, unfortunately, my CT-fu is not that strong. I, for instance, am not supposed to know what's a functor category. I'll try to make as much sense as I can given that, but would it be possible to reformulate this in simpler terms, like what folks reading "Topoi" are supposed to know by the point of formulating the notion of an elementary topos?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not seeing how your "image along the diagonal functor" construction results in the interpretation of $\pi_2 : \{ (p, q) \in \Omega \times \Omega \mid p \rightarrow q \} \to \Omega$ as the subobject classifier in the case of $C$ being "the two-object one-nontrivial-morphism category" as I found in my answer.

Comment: I don't see why $\chi_x^\alpha : Gx \to \Omega$ would form a cocone for $G$.  That would amount to requiring that $\chi_y^\alpha \circ f = \chi_x^\alpha$ whenever $f : x\to y$ is a morphism in $C$ - or equivalently, that each commutative square in $\alpha : F \to G$ is in fact a pullback square, which isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: Hmm, I probably mis-quantified in the computation I made; but I believe the proof works in essence. Let me come back at this in a while, if I have time. Yes, anyway, the argument is probably slightly flawed.

Comment: I also just noticed one of the links on the right shows $\mathbf{FinSets}^{\mathbb{N}}$ does not have a subobject classifier - so there are going to need to be some restrictions on $\mathcal{E}$ and $C$.  From a generalization of my answer, I think that could be a family of possible restrictions such as $C$ is finite, or $\mathcal{E}$ has all small limits, or $\mathcal{E}$ has countable limits and $C$ has countably many morphisms with any given source object, or ...